# Can't insert into an Oracle table

Tags: c#, oracle11g, insert

I'm about to make an insert into a table `CORRESPONDANT`, I have a sequence that auto_increment the ID value, this my table:

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5oN7.png)
The sequence is name: `SEQ_ID`.

I'm running this command :

```
INSERT INTO CORRESPONDANT (ID, DESIGNATION, REGROUPEMENT, FISCALID, ADRESSE, TEL, FAX, EMAIL) 
VALUES (SEQ_ID.NEXTVAL, 'Designation', 'regrouppement', '2az22z5a', 'ghazela', 1234, 56789, 123789, 'nabil@parrot.com')
```

But I get an error :

> ORA-00913: too many values

I need to make this command run so I can insert data from my C# code.

Note : I'm using Oracle 11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there are 'too many value' when you entered 'TEL' or 'FAX'. Because, you are trying to add two phone numbers in 'TEL', which the query syntax is taken as 'two separate values'. One for 'TEL'='1234', 'FAX'='56789','EMAIL'='123789'. And actual value of email is declared as extra value. 
SOLUTION: If your column type is 'vchar' then simply follow the bellow query syntax:

INSERT INTO CORRESPONDANT (ID, DESIGNATION ,REGROUPEMENT ,FISCALID, ADRESSE ,TEL , FAX, EMAIL) VALUES (SEQ_ID.NEXTVAL,'Designation','regrouppement','2az22z5a','ghazela',**'1234,56789'**,123789,'nabil@parrot.com')

Hope this will work... 
Happy Coding!

Comment: well, i changed all my column as vchar2, and i modified the query as follow : 
INSERT INTO CORRESPONDANT (ID, DESIGNATION ,REGROUPEMENT ,FISCALID, ADRESSE ,TEL , FAX, EMAIL) VALUES (SEQ_ID.NEXTVAL,'Designation','regrouppement','2az22z5a','ghazela','1234','56789','123789','nabil@parrot.com') 
this didnt work too, " ORA-00913: too many values
 "i think this is coming from my SEQ_ID. can you confirm ?

Comment: Well i found that i didnt add my VILLEID, now it workes, thanks for your help.. this the query now
INSERT INTO CORRESPONDANT (ID, DESIGNATION ,REGROUPEMENT ,FISCALID, ADRESSE ,VILLEID,TEL , FAX, EMAIL) VALUES (SEQ_ID.NEXTVAL,'Designation','regrouppement','2az22z5a','ghazela','1234','56789','123789','nabil@parrot.com')